# How to explain Susannah's oddly cold response to Maud's insights?

Tags: the-dark-tower

During Stephen King's *The Dark Tower III: The Waste Lands*, the Ka-tet visits the city of Lud where Eddie and Susannah get into a fight with the inhabiting faction of the pubes, ultimately having to gun down a few of them. But once that's over and Eddie and Susannah convince them to bring them to Blaine, the remaining Pubes, in particular a woman called Maud, get unexpectedly emotional and considerate, from mourning the death of her beloved one to cursing guns altogether:

> “Come on, Maud,” Jeeves said, and helped her up. “Ay. Let’s finish with them.” She surveyed Susannah and Eddie again, her eyes stem but somehow confused, as well. “Gods curse my eyes that they should ever have happened on you two in the first place. And gods curse the guns ye carry, as well, for they were always the springhead of our troubles.”
>       And with that attitude, Susannah thought, your troubles are going to last at least a thousand years, sugar.

But I was a little confused at Susannah's reaction here. Her response to Maud's rather insightful general remark about guns and the demise they ultimately bring seems to disregard those feelings altogether. Especially after she (and Eddie) even felt a little remorse about killing the others just a few sentences earlier this somewhat cold and ultimately violence-glorifying reaction from Susannah's side seemed really odd to me. I feel I'm either misunderstanding Maud's words or Susannah's thoughts here or am missing something else. So **what was Susannah really trying to say with her thoughts there** and how does it figure into this situation and her character?

Comment: Why can't Maud and Susannah simply have opposite attitudes here? What you might view as insightful, Susannah might view as naïve. Or she might view Maud as refusing to take responsibility for her actions and those of her fellows, instead blaming Susannah etc.

Comment: @Adamant Sounds like you're about to write an answer.

Comment: If only. I've never read the series - I'm just guessing. But this does sound like just a philosophical difference between Maud and Susannah.

Comment: @Adamant Well, yeah, I guess it is. What I would like to know is *specifically what* that difference is, and how it *figures into Susannah's character*, who I just hadn't expected such a response from.